# Consultation about convert xml to text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

i need to isolate xml file to string val's

and put any tag to text field

i have this code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1255">
<title>JS Test</title>

<script>
  function loadXMLDoc()
  {
    var xmlhttp;
    var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("");
    alert("Start");
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET","MyIP:8082/My_ws?applic=MyApp&branch=493&itemno=55329",false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
  }
</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="myDiv"><h2>JS Test</h2></div>
  <button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Get</button>
</body>
</html>
```

and i get this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1255" ?>
<itemQuery>
<branch>493</branch>
<item>55329</item>
<itemName>milk</itemName>
<retCode>0</retCode></itemQuery>
```

how to put any field in text field like this:

```
branch = 493
item = 55329
itemName = milk
```

thanks

Comment: Hi, first please check your code twice before posting: you don't have any opening `<script>` in your `head` section. Then, what did you look at? You seem to post random code... What is the text field where you want to put your data for example?
The best way to get a good answer is to provide a simplified and easy-to-use sample, on jsfiddle for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery parsexml: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsexml/

```
var thexml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1255" ?><itemQuery><branch>493</branch><item>55329</item><itemName>milk</itemName><retCode>0</retCode></itemQuery>';


xmlDoc = $.parseXML( thexml );
var $xml = $( xmlDoc );
var $title = $xml.find( "branch" );

$("#txtBranch").val($title.text());
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/tgda2oLy/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by looping through the nodes of `xmlhttp.responseXML`.

Note that using this attribute (or `responseText`) will only work on Internet Explorer. You should therefore consider using a wrapper that will make sure that your AJAX requests will work on most common browsers, like for example jQuery.

Comment: can you help me more with example ?

Comment: how to looping through the nodes of xmlhttp.responseXML and insert every tag to Separate string

Comment: Please refer to the documentation for the type of `responseXML`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms757878(v=vs.85).aspx